# WinJS listview progress bar

Tags: microsoft-metro, winjs

### WinJS listview progress bar

Hi I am working a WinJS application.I have a listview.I need to add a progress bar when loading the listview..How can  do that?

Comment: refer [progress controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465487.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

WinJS ListView control already includes a progress ring that is displayed when the listView is fetching data.

The progress ring goes away as soon as the first item in listView is rendered. Refer this sample for more details: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-performance-39fb71f0

Answer (score 0):

Either manually create a progress control and show/hide the ListView, as suggested by @Sushil or implement a custom [IListDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211786.aspx) which returns data in an asynchronous fashion.

In this case, the ListView will take care of displaying the loading indicator all by itself while it waits for the data source. I recommend taking this approach even though it may have a slightly steeper learning curve. Additionally, you can register event listeners on the `loadingstatechanged` event of the ListView to do further processing.